# What's the kanji for "appointed location"

Tags: words

Can't seem to remember.

Kind of like how 当日 means "appointed day," I'm pretty sure I've seen a kanji for something like 当所 but I can't find one. I've found 当地 but I don't know if it has the same implication as 当日.

Comment: Are you sure it uses 当? I feel that "in the appointed place" should be 現地で.

Comment: What exactly to you mean by "appointed"?  The kanji 当 usually means "this" or "that".  For example, `試験当日` means `the day of the test`.

Comment: @istrasci Unlike those 当時, 当社, 当店 etc. are "this X" or "our X", 当日 means "the day of (event)", so OP's right in "appointed day". However, the counterpart "appointed location" doesn't belong to 当 but is 現地.

Comment: how about 例の~ ? It refers to a ~ established by previous discourse.

Comment: @discardthis It's a good virtue to express one's gratitude to those who reach out for us, but the community gains more if you simply pay it forward helping someone else and accepting an answer. Just saying :) Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to learn more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the "当所" entry in 大辞林, which says this word means "this place".
But I cannot find the "当所" entry in 新明解. The word "当所" is rarely used, so 新明解 may omit this word.

Since "当所" has a same pronunciation as "当初", which means "at first" or "at the beginning", and a use of "当初" is more frequent than a use of "当所", "当所" used in talks may be confusing.

When I want to say something meaning "a place where the specified event will be held", I use a word "現地".